# How do I fix debian jessie shutdown error?

Tags: debian, kernel, logs, panic

I recently got a pc and I installed debian jessie. And everything is going well, the problem is when I try to shut down the pc, because it freezes, the same happens if I try to restart, suspend. The pc is an acer Aspire E 15 and processor: intel celeron 2.16Ghz dual-core. In the log that implements to know what was happening tells me the following:

[image]

[image]

Someone who knows what's going on?